# breaking time segments (shifts) by subsegments (day, night, etc)

Tags: php, algorithm, time, timespan

I have a problem in a small project in PHP and can't think of an algorithm that considers every case. The problem gives a file with two constants and an array of info.

```
<?php


// The start and end of nighttime hours
$SETTINGS_nighttime_start = '22:00';
$SETTINGS_nighttime_end   = '07:00';

// Employees and their shifts
$EMPLOYEES = array(

    '0' => array(
        'name'        => 'Bernice Lyons',
        'shift_start' => '15:15',
        'shift_end'   => '23:45'
    ),

    '1' => array(
        'name'        => 'Gregg Santos',
        'shift_start' => '10:00',
        'shift_end'   => '22:00'
    ),

    '2' => array(
        'name'        => 'Bennie Montgomery',
        'shift_start' => '22:30',
        'shift_end'   => '08:00'
    ),

    '3' => array(
        'name'        => 'Nelson Austin',
        'shift_start' => '20:00',
        'shift_end'   => '10:00'
    ),

    '4' => array(
        'name'        => 'Garrett Sims',
        'shift_start' => '09:00',
        'shift_end'   => '17:00'
    ),

    '5' => array(
        'name'        => 'Joanna Pratt',
        'shift_start' => '23:00',
        'shift_end'   => '06:00'
    )

);
```

?>

So I need to write an algorithm that considers every case and calculates time someone worked day and time worked at night.

What statement I should use to cover the case and get right result :

```
startShift = 20:00
endShift = 10:00
```

should result

```
daytimeWork = 05:00
nighttimeWork = 09:00
```

I have so far got the data and print them on screen but I have a problem with calculating daytime and nighttime shift times

The pseudocode I wrote for this case I wrote is

```
if(startShift<22:00 && endShift>07:00){
   nighttimeWork = 09:00;
   daytimeWork = shiftLength - 09:00;
}
```

but in the statement includes the case

```
startShift = 10:00
endShift = 20:00
```

I am so frustrated. Please someone help.

Comment: Why can't you just work on the assumption that if they left before they entered you should just add 24 hours to the length of the shift. `$shiftLength = strToTime($shiftStart) - strtoTime($shiftEnd); if($shiftLength < 0){ $shiftLength += 24 * 60 * 60; }`

Comment: If the start is greater than the end, subtract the start from 24 (night) and the daytime is the same as the end shift number. If the start is less than the end, subtract start from end for daytime. All this with appropriate adjustments based on your settings.

Comment: So you say to add an if clause that checks if (start>end) do the calculations. It may works

Comment: scragar, why add 24 hours on shiftLength? I just want to find how many hours someone worked day and night, I don't think that can help

Comment: So Jay I'll try this later, and get back to you if have a problem, but seems logical and I think it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @Andreas777 my Psuedo-ish code would generate a negative number for people who worked a night shift, adding 24 hours brings it back up to the correct number of hours worked.

Comment: I don't think it will, because adding 24 to -14 i.e. will not return 14 but 10. Anyway, the problem wasn't with the shiftLength but with calculating shifts.

Comment: @Andreas777 You're actually thinking about it wrong, someone who works from 10PM (22:00) to 6AM(06:00) has obviously worked 8 hours, this maths does end(6) - start(20), comes up with -16, then adds 24 to bring it back up to 8.

Comment: I got what you mean now. Because in some calculations when I subtract times I must sub the result from 00:00 to get the right times.

Comment: For doing the calculations I use strtotime at every hour. This gives me a timestamp, am I right? This means that when I get a shiftLength = -52200 means -52200 seconds from UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Hey . Andreas. Did you get solution of this?

Comment: Man, sorry but is quite long since I did it. I think the last answer I posted was working, but you have to try and see...

Answer (score 2):

This problem requires you to start with shifts: time intervals denoted by start/end times. It requires you to break those shifts into shiftlets: smaller nonoverlapping time intervals the union of which span the same start/end time.

Consider a software operation that takes a shift item as input, and breaks it into shiftlets.

For example:

```
startShift = 20:00  endShift = 10:00
```

First break this shift into shiftlets that don't span midnight:

```
startShift = 20:00  endShift = 00:00
startShift = 00:00  endShift = 10:00
```

Then break these shiftlets into shiftlets that don't cross the day/night boundary.

```
startShift = 20:00  endShift = 00:00
startShift = 00:00  endShift = 07:00
startShift = 07:00  endShift = 10:00
```

Then classify each shiftlet by day or night, then add up the times, and you're done.

Comment: Yes I thought doing something like that but is a bit complicated with all the srttotime and date functions, because all formats must be of "H:i" and seemed overwhelming